# Replication from On-premise MySQL to AWS MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-administration, percona

I'm trying to setup replication from on-premise mysql to AWS mysql rds only for selected databases.
I configured replicate-do-db & replicate-do-table to filter databases from RDS parameter list,But its replicating all the databases from Onpremise MySQL,and replicate-do-db & replicate-do-table looks empty in rds SHOW SLAVE STATUS also.Below are the screenshots.
I tried restart of rds,changing the parameter group.Nothing worked.Am i missing any additional configuration on RDS.

```
Onpremis MySQL version --> 8.0.16
RDS MySQL version --> 8.0.16
```

[image replication filter RDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBN7o.png)

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: master_host
                  Master_User: root
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: master.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 195
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000030
                Relay_Log_Pos: 275
        Relay_Master_Log_File: master.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: innodb_memcache.cache_policies,innodb_memcache.config_options,mysql.plugin,mysql.rds_configuration,mysql.rds_history,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.rds_sysinfo
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 195
              Relay_Log_Space: 596
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 11
                  Master_UUID: 51b1a20a-8b30-11ec-8f2e-0242ac12000b
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 32d52d6b-89f0-11ec-b4f7-0abf88ecd642:1-96,
51b1a20a-8b30-11ec-8f2e-0242ac12000b:28,
c3e9fc5e-89c3-11ec-81f8-0242ac12000b:30-188
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I have not configured any binlog-do-db on as master has some other slaves which is on premise which does't need replication filters.

Comment: Is it manditory to set binlog-do-db on master also , As far as i understand slave reads  filter db events from relay logs on slave. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: You don't have to set `binlog-do-db` on master, but  you need to tell the replica which statements to read. [Take a look here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binlog-replication-configuration-overview.html).

Comment: I already configured replication-do-db & replication-do-table in paramter group and executed set_external_master spc on RDS, Also check attached image.slave connected to master but replication filters not working.

Comment: I tested same with MySQL RDS 8.0.26 ,Replication filters are working. But not sure why its not working on RDS 8.0.16.